# Inserting double quotes string within formula within VBA (Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to insert a function looking like this, using VBA:

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B12,AASD!A:B,2,0)),"Check #",VLOOKUP(B12,AASD!A:`B,2,0))

Code from VBA:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B12,AASD!A:B,2,0)),"Check AA#",VLOOKUP(B12,AASD!A:B,2,0))"
```

Issue is the "" quotes for inserting the string in the IF formula messes up the "" quotes in VBA.

Is there a clever work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just double them up

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B12,AASD!A:B,2,0)),""Check AA#"",VLOOKUP(B12,AASD!A:B,2,0))"
```

You can also use Chr(34) in place of a single set of quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, that formula can be cut in half with IFERROR.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Formula = _
   "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B12, AASD!A:B, 2, 0), ""Check AA#"")"
```