# Inserting double quotes string within formula within VBA - Getting "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying run the following line in a VBA script:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("C13").formula = "=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""Beloeb"";LikviditetEgenkapitalPivot!$A$3;""Dato"";$B2022;""Dimm4"";C$11))=TRUE;0;(GETPIVOTDATA(""Beloeb"";LikviditetEgenkapitalPivot!$A$6;""Dato"";$B2022;""Dimm4"";C$11)))"
```

I'm getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I've been looking at the similar questions below (and followed the guide) - but I'm still in "dead water"

I've also tried to use the "chr(34)" method.

Any suggestions?

[Inserting double quotes string within formula within VBA (Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768609/inserting-double-quotes-string-within-formula-within-vba-excel)

[VBA Application Defined or Object-Defined Error with Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237506/vba-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-with-formula)

Comment: Looks OK, except I think you need to use commas (`,`) instead of semicolons (`;`) in VBA, no matter what your international list spearator

Comment: Asked 1000nd times: You need to specify the formula in *english* format, replace the semicolon by comma. And I will never understand why such complex things are not written into a variable so that you can check the content with the debugger.

Comment: You can reduce complexity of the formula by using `IFERROR` instead of `IF(ISERROR ...`. Tipp: to avoid the semicolon/comma-issue: write the formula to a cell, select that cell. Then in VBA editor in the immediate window type `?selection.formula` and you will get as a result the correct version for VBA